How do we fix background evidence in Bayesian thinking?
The best way to illustrate this is using the example of fine tuning.
The fine tuning argument goes that the constants of the universe are fine tuned in such a way that if they were any different, life would not have arisen. The probability of this is considered extremely low. Let’s assume this is true.
Intuitively, as long as the probability of a cosmic designer existing and wanting to create a universe like this is higher, it makes sense to prefer a designer over the hypothesis that this fine tuning occurred by chance.
The question now is: when trying to calculate this probability, how does one fix the background evidence? For example, if one does not take anything into account, and tries to “apriori” think of all the possible things that could exist, god may seem to be incredibly unlikely, perhaps much more unlikely than the fine tuned constants. After all, there are an infinite number of things that one could imagine exist, and there would seem to be no apriori reason to prefer god to exist over other alternatives (unless one believes that god is logically necessary, but let’s assume that’s not true)
However, if we take into account the universe we live in, we may now constrain our possibilities. For example, clearly a god that wanted to create a universe with life on every planet, could not exist. This is because life does not exist on every planet. Thus, these kinds of possibilities now get “pruned” out of the total sample space (I.e. the denominator of the probability fraction gets smaller), making the resulting probability of god existing seemingly higher.
How does one, then, decide how much background evidence one needs to fix before calculating probabilities?

"Thus, these kinds of possibilities now get “pruned” out of the total sample space (I.e. the denominator of the probability fraction gets smaller), making the resulting probability of god existing seemingly higher." - Can you please justify this part using math? Please write the formulas/equations.

@user80226 well a sample space is the set of possible outcomes. If certain outcomes are already impossible, there is no need to include them in the sample space. For example, “7” is not a possible outcome for a dice roll. If it was, the denominator when calculating the probability of an outcome would go from 6 to 7.

A sample space is not a denominator. This is confusing. Can you please write the math explicitly?

@user80226 the number of events in the sample space is. So for dice, if the sample space is {1,2,3,4,5,6}, then the probability of any one of them is 1/6. If we add an event to make the sample space {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, the probability of any one of them becomes 1/7.

"then the probability of any one of them is 1/6" - That presupposes uniform distribution, why not a different distribution? (By the way, the uniform distribution doesn't exist for infinite countable sets.) "If we add an event" - You can add outcomes to your sample space, not events.

If something exists its probability is 100%. If the "constants of the universe" were different, then different forms of life would have arisen, and the present ones would not. It's back to Douglas Adams: the chances of there being a depression of the exact shape for that particular puddle is small, but puddles will form in other shaped depressions. IMO life is inevitable and the idea is insepararable from the idea of "the universe".
